# Работа с данными константных полей

Tags: c#

Такое константное поле объявить можно:

```
private const int minute = 60_000;
```

А почему нельзя объявить такое константное поле ?

```
private const TimeSpan minute = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: перенесите UPD в ответ

Comment: Можете не const, а readonly сделать, если хотите защитить от изменения в процессе работы.

Comment: @ГеннадийП: Тогда уж `static readonly`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прошу прощения - всё оказалось довольно просто:

**Ошибка компилятора CS0283**

Тип `type` не может быть объявлен как `const`.

Тип, указанный в объявлении `const`, должен быть `byte` , `sbyte` , `ushort` , `short` ,`uint` , `int` , `ulong` , `long` , `char` , `float` , `double` , `decimal` , `bool`, `string` , типом перечисления или ссылочным типом, которому присвоено значение `null` . Каждое константное выражение должно возвращать значение целевого типа или типа, который неявно преобразуется в целевой тип.

Comment: В чем суть ответа, в том что перевод кривой или в чем именно? Почему текст вставлен картинкой? Текст, вставленный картинкой, невозможно найти через поиск.

Comment: @aepot нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Cначала не понимал почему не мог задать `TimeSpan` как `const`. А оказалось что ошибка компилятора очень подробна была описана и можно было по сути не спрашивать тут. Про картинки понял, чуть позже изменю на текст.

Comment: @aepot картинки поменял на текст

Comment: Так гораздо лучше.